# Does a Mutex ever close by itself?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I'm trying to work out when is the right time to use `ReleaseMutex`, and when is the right time to use `Close`.

We are (effectively) writing an "auto-updater" type application in C#. The user can run more than one instance of the auto-updater at the same time, however each one must wait for other instances to finish before it proceeds. So effectively, the application flow is as follows:

- Start updater, create a mutex (`new Mutex(false, "MyMutex", out isCreator)`)
- Check for existing running instances (`Mutex.WaitOne`)

  - If there are existing instances running, wait for them to complete
  - If there are no other instances running, proceed with the update
- Release the mutex

It's that final step that I'm wondering about. If a particular application instance **created** the Mutex, then I figured it would be safe for that instance to also **close** the Mutex; but, I'm not sure what this would do to other application instances that are then waiting on that Mutex.

A safer option seems to be to let each application simply **release** the mutex; however, I don't know in this case if the mutex would ever be destroyed?

```
private const string _mutexName = "NinjaMutexAwesomePants";
private static int _threadId;

void Main()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(AcquireMutex);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(AcquireMutex);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(AcquireMutex);
}

void Trace(int threadId, string text, params object[] args) 
{
    var trace = String.Concat(
        String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss.ffff} T{1}: ", DateTime.Now, threadId),
        String.Format(text, args));

    Console.WriteLine(trace);
}

void AcquireMutex()
{
    var threadId = Interlocked.Increment(ref _threadId);

    Trace(threadId, "Started!");

    bool createdNew;
    var mutex = new Mutex(false, _mutexName, out createdNew);

    if (createdNew)
        Trace(threadId, "I am the creator!");
    else
        Trace(threadId, "I did not create the mutex.");

    try
    {
        var isOwner = mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        if (isOwner)
            Trace(threadId, "I am the owner of the mutex!");
        else
            Trace(threadId, "I couldn't acquire the mutex.");

        if (isOwner) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            if (createdNew)
                mutex.Close();
            else
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();

            Trace(threadId, "I have released the mutex.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace(threadId, "{0}: {1}", ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However, this didn't really clear things up for me. Seemingly, **always** using `ReleaseMutex` is the safest option (instead of calling `Close`), however this also seems like the mutex is never closed even after all threads have released the mutex. In fact, in the code above - if the creator thread also closes the mutex, the consumer threads can never acquire it.

So, my questions are twofold:

1. What's the best policy for acquiring/releasing a mutex in this scenario?
2. If I only ever use `ReleaseMutex`, does the mutex close itself after all threads have released it?

Comment: You can read about underlying Win32 [Mutext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details. `Close` will close handle in this process (can't impact other processes) - that why your test fails after `Close`.

Comment: Thanks @alexei-levenkov, that certainly explains the behaviour I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to implement `IDisposable` for this purpose

```
class Updater : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Mutex _mutex;

    public Updater(string mutexName)
    {
        bool createdNew;
        _mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexName, out createdNew);
        if (!_mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) throw new Exception("I could not acquire mutex");

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // Perform the update
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        _mutex.Close();
    }
}


using (var updater = new Updater("NinjaMutexAwesomePants"))
{
    updater.Update();
}
```